# Up button in Android ActionBar Compatibility, it is possible?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, back, up-button

I'm using the `actionBar` compatibility api for my app.

I'm trying to show the up button at the left of the app icon. I know how to do that with the original `ActionBar` class, but I can't figure out how to do the same with the ActionBar Compat

(I don't have any method like `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in the original ActionBar class).

Someone knows how to do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the ActionBar with the Android Compat library, use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) for ActionBar on API 10 or lower.

Comment: Yes, but the Ancetral Navigation is a feature of the ActionBar. ;)